# Static contents stored in the "/images" directory not being served, as the URL becomes relative to the" /css" directory

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-boot

I have all the css files stored in `src/main/resources/public/css` directoy and all the images in the `src/main/resources/public/images` directory.

So when i try to access images from style sheets, for example: `background-image: url("/images/dp.jpg");`, This URL becomes relative to `css` directory hence images are not being served.. 
The only way it is working now is putting all the images in the css folder itself and specifying background as `background-image: url("dp.jpg");`.
But i don't want to change the directory structre this way

I tried specifying fully qualified url like `background-image: url("http://localhost:8080//images/dp.jpg");`but this is not working either. 
Is there an easy way to access images in the `/images` directory, from stylesheets in the `/css` directory?

Comment: Did you try to add <meta name="base" content="/" /> at HEAD part of html content ?

Comment: @KadirÇetintaş Static contents are accessible inside HTML , But  i've put stylesheets in `css` folder,so when accessing images from css, URL becoming relative to css folder

Comment: I think the browsers is taking care of the base tag even you are trying to access inside file url's at css tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths inside url() are taken relative to the directory of css file itself. So you can change your urls in css like below.

```
background-image: url("../images/dp.jpg")
```